# How can I define fieldset border color?

Tags: html, css, border

I want to set border color of field set. I am using class but this is not working properly because i want to remove fieldset default border color.
so how can I use fieldset border color.

```
<fieldset class="field_set">
    <legend>box</legend>
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tr>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
           </tr>
      </table>
</fieldset>
```

css

```
.field_set{
 border-color:#F00;
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It does appear red on Firefox and IE 8. But perhaps you need to change the `border-style` too.

```css
.field_set{
  border-color: #F00;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="field_set">
  <legend>box</legend>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Comment: The portion within the braces can be shortened to: `border: solid #F00;`

Comment: `border-style: solid` before using this I was getting a reddish-black border, as if the fieldset had two borders very close to each other. I was trying to set red border, fieldset default was black. After setting border-style it became the true red I wanted. I am using chrome  91.0.4472.124. Still not sure how border-style helps. Just know that it works.

Answer (score 11):

It works for me when I define the complete `border` property. (JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MJKPR/))

```
.field_set{
 border: 1px #F00 solid;
}​
```

the reason is the `border-style` that is set to `none` by default for fieldsets. You need to override that as well.

Answer (score 9):

I added it for all fieldsets with

```
fieldset {
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
    }
```

I didnt work if I set it separately using for example

> border-color : red

. Then a black line was drawn next to the red line.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want 3D border use:

```
border:#f00 1px solid;
```