# iOS7 Safari CSS Border around fieldset is not shown

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, ios7

I used the fieldset CSS property for my website. Recently I found that iOS7 Safari or Chrome does not support fieldset border setting.

Check the following page:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset

on Windows, you will see the border around fieldset

on iOS7, borders around fieldset are not shown.

I googled it but could not find anything relevant.

Do you know any solution for that (except replacing fieldset with div) ?

Regards,
Berk

Answer (score 0):

Just style the `fieldset` element, like this: `fieldset { border: 1px solid #000; }`. This is ultimately a more dependable, cross-browser solution that will look the same in any browser.

Comment: No it does not work. Borders around fieldset are still not shown. Tried it with fieldset { border: 1px solid #000; }. You can check it yourself at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset

Comment: I did try it at that link, and it did work for me. I set it up in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5puKs/

Comment: Are you sure that you are using iOS 7 Safari or Chrome? Because I just checked the link with iPad and it still does not show borders around fieldset.

Comment: I just checked the JSFiddle I made on my iPhone in Safari, which has iOS 7, and it worked. My guess is that you have some kind of bug in your CSS. You can try "inspect element" in your browser and see what properties are being applied to your fieldset. Maybe it is inheriting some kind of "border: 0;" property.

Comment: I just tested your link (jsfiddle) with iPhone 7 and as you told, everything is working as expected.

But borders around fieldset are not shown if I use an iPad. 

I believe iPad and iPhone use the same Webkit version. But still, to verify the problem,

I will try with a different iPad tomorrow.

Thanks

Comment: opened [jsfiddle.net/5puKs](http://jsfiddle.net/5puKs) on my iPad (iOS 7.0.3), and the border NOT shown. :-(

Comment: I upgrade the iOS to 7.0.4, Clear history, cookie and data belong to safari. Open the page (jsfiddle.net/5puKs) again. The border still NOT shown. Any solution?

Comment: Maybe this thread will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741333/how-can-i-define-fieldset-border-color