# can we insert the values of textboxes to sql database using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NewMyprofile.aspx.cs" Inherits="NewMyprofile" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><b>Personal Details</b></legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>*FirstName</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <b>*LastName</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>*SurName</b>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txtsurname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>Phone</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txtphone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <b>Extension</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txtextension" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>Mobile</b>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtmob" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>*Sex</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbmale" runat="server" />
                                <b>Male</b>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdfemale" runat="server" />
                                <b>Female</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <b>Maritial Status</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdmarry" runat="server" />
                                <b>Married</b>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="Rdsingle" runat="server" />
                                <b>Single</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>*Email Id</b>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailId" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>Address</b>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtaddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><b>Education Details</b></legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>*Qualification </b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtqual" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>*College</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtclg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>*University</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txtuniv" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>*Year Of Passing</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyop" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1990" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1991" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1992" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1993" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1994" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1995" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1996" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1997" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1998" Value="8"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="1999" Value="9"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2000" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2001" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2002" Value="12"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2003" Value="13"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2004" Value="14"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2005" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2006" Value="16"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2007" Value="17"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2008" Value="18"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2009" Value="19"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2010" Value="20"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2011" Value="21"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2012" Value="22"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2013" Value="23"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2014" Value="24"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2015" Value="25"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2016" Value="26"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2017" Value="27"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2018" Value="28"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2019" Value="29"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="2020" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>Address</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtadd1" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

in this page i need to make a clent side validations for all mandatory fields
```

like textboxes,radio buttons,dropdown list using java script......as i was very new to this so

please kindly help me over this various types of validations using javascript

i have bit knowledge on validations in .cs files but i dont have pror knowledge while dealing with javascript validations

Comment: have you tried anything in javascript?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=client+side+validation&oq=client+side+validation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5131j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=94&ie=UTF-8#q=client-side+javascript+form+validation+tutorial

Comment: thank u very much @LOL ur link is useful to me very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function Validate() {
            if(document.getElementById('txtfname').value=="")
            {
               alert('txtfname empty');
            }

             if(document.getElementById('rdmarry').checked==false)
            {
               alert('rdmarry not selected');
            }
             var ddlyop= document.getElementById('ddlyop');
            if( ddlyop.options[ddlyop.selectedIndex].value=="")
            {
                  alert('ddlyop not selected');
            }
       </script>
```

You can validate your required controls same as this..

You can call this function on onclientclick event of a button..

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClientClick="Validate();return false;"/>
```

Comment: for radiobuttons fields .....and drop down fields?

Comment: Can we write stord procedure in javascript to store the values of textboxes in db on client click save?

Comment: Sorry,From my limited knowledge I can say no..Ask experts about that,Regards..

Comment: so nice of u...it brought me a great jeal of interest with ur inspiration and support

Comment: sorry i just ticked every answer which helped me.....to encourgae i donno the real rules

Comment: how to get border lines of fieldset with different colors

Comment: Please apply css style for fieldset..Refer this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741333/how-can-i-define-fieldset-border-color

Comment: In this link Fieldset has a class="field_set"..

Comment: If you have any other doubts regarding that you can post it as a new question,Regards..

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript function :-

```
function validateForm(){
 var mandatoryFields = document.getElementById('txtfname').value=="" || document.getElementById('txtLname').value=="";
 //and other mandatory textboxes with id
 if(madatoryFields){
   alert("Please fill all mandatory fields.")
   return;
 }
}

<asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="validateForm"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can attach a javascript method on "Onclick" of button (of ID="btnsubmit") Like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Validate()"/>
```

And define this javascript method in script tag like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function Validate() {
            if(document.getElementById('txtfname').value==""||
               document.getElementById('txtlname').value=="" ||                 
               document.getElementById('Txtsurname').value==""||
               document.getElementById('Txtphone').value=="" ||
               document.getElementById('Txtextension').value=="" ||
               document.getElementById('txtaddress').value=="" ||
               document.getElementById('ddlyop').value=="") //add fields which you wants to validate here
            {
               alert("Mandatory information missing");//your specific message
            }
       </script>
```

Comment: for radio button check cant we include? it is also a mandatory field